# how to upgrade react-native-cli?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

Check current react native CLI version

```
react-native -v
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.61.5
```

I use the following commands to upgrade global `react-native-cli` verison

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

but now check current react native cli version, it's still `v1.0.0`

```
react-native -v
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.61.5
```

How to upgrade the `react-native-cli`?

Comment: I found the root cause why I can get the updated version of `react-native-cli`. it's because I have installed two react-native,`/Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.0/bin/react-native` and 
`/usr/local/bin/react-native`, the second one is not installed by npm, so after I remove the folder, I can get latest information:  `react-native -v`
`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`
`react-native: 0.61.5`

Answer (score 2):

**The Homebrew way**

Remove globally first if needed

```sh
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

or

```sh
yarn remove react-native-cli
```

Install brew

```sh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Install it with brew

```sh
brew install react-native-cli
```

Upgrade in future

```sh
brew upgrade react-native-cli
```

Comment: Thanks for including the upgrade method for next time as well!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `react-native 0.61.5` you need to install `react-native-cli` version `3.0.0` or above according to [Compatibility](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#compatibility) of React Native CLI.

If you have already installed a version of react-native CLI, uninstall it using

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Then try to install react-native CLI as below,

```
npm install react-native-cli@3.0.0
```

Hope this will help you.

**Note:**
This may not work with `react-native-cli` version `4.0.0` or above.